# How do I open Git bash in ubuntu 18.04

Tags: git

I have installed Git bash in ubuntu 18.04 using sudo apt install git-all. Now I want to enter some SSH key command to connect it to my github account, But I can't access to my gitbash. How can I open gitbash on my ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to open a specific "gitbash" in Ubuntu. You can just run git commands in your Bash terminal. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/11491897/7746941